# UITableView Alignment with UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a `UITableView` line up with the height sizing of paragraphs in a `UITextView`. **Example:** The timestamps to the left are what I am trying to do. I changed my code to use UIView's instead of TVcells to see what was wrong and you can see the orange view is overlapping the cyan one, meaning that the views don't actually line up but they overlap. **NOTE: I am wanting to use the TableView not UIView's** [image] I am having trouble understanding how the text heights are calculated in iOS. I am using the below code to get the heights of each `paragraph`:

```
 let liveParagraphView = textView.selectionRects(for: txtRange).reduce(CGRect.null) { $0.union($1.rect) }
```

After this I calculate the height of each then feed that into my `UITableView heightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let models = getParagraphModel()

        let height = models[indexPath.row].height
        let finalHeight = models[indexPath.row].height

        let heightValue = finalHeight
        return CGFloat(heightValue);
    }
```

Every line has different height values but even when using these values it's not lining up. The problem seems to be that every line calculates a Y Position which is not directly under the line before it. It's **ON TOP OF!!** Resulting in the UITableView not being alined when new cells are added and that 'overlay' of the selectionRects isn't taken into account. Am I correct by this? How could I go about achieving this?

Comment: Do you want to dynamic cell height when textView editing? Please explain more.

Comment: @EmreCiftci Yep each paragraph would have a corresponding TableViewCell which would grow or shrink depending on the size of the paragraph. This is the same feature that is in the ‘Noted’ App on the AppStore

Comment: @EmreCiftci Any ideas?

Comment: Selection Rects overlap... that is, the bottom of a line's selection rectangle will overlap with the TOP of the next line's selection rectangle. So the Y position of line 1 may be Zero, with a height of 22.5, and the Y position of line 2 may be 21.5 with a height of 22.5. To do what you want, you'll probably need to track the adjacent rectangles to determine the actual heights you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Firstly you should set your textView (which is in the cell) dynamic height:

```
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
textView.sizeToFit()
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Then calculate your textView's number of lines in `textDidChange` etc. for update tableView's layout.

`let numOfLines = (yourTextView.contentSize.height / yourTextView.font.lineHeight) as? Int`

When textView's text one line down you should update tableView layout:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

And then you should set your tableView cell's intrinsicContentSize for dynamic rowHeight:

- Set your cell's (which is the contains textView) layout without static height,
- Set your tableView's `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight`:

  ```
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 // whatever you want
  ```

So now you have tableView cell with dynamicHeight

Comment: Hi Emre! Is this solution on the basis that each paragraph is inside a Cell?

Comment: This answer about textView with dynamic height in tableView cell. You can set your textView in tableView cell and configure it to get height from it's content.

Comment: Hi Emre, Im wanting there to be a cell for every paragraph in the textView. Not for the whole UITextView. I have given an example in the photo above. Each of the buttons would need to be in a separate Cell.